# Rails doesn't need index method in controller defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I noticed that an index view is routed correctly even if there isn't a controller method index.

As an example, the `routes.rb` has this route

```
AppName::Application.routes.draw do
  get 'about' => "about#index"
end
```

My controller looks like this with no index method (`def index end`)

```
class AboutController < ApplicationController
end
```

and I have a view called `index.html.erb` in the views/about folder

What's happening here? Is this a case of rails magic where they automatically show the view even if there is no controller method? I couldn't find any documentation on this...

Comment: Yeah, that's new; the controller docs have not been updated to reflect this yet--the docs imply you still need an empty method.

Comment: Wow ! I run into a security issue with a forgotten view, that was suddenlt exposed... looking forward to override this behaviour!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have the view file, it'll go ahead and render that implicitly, as documented [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action)

See also, this SO thread on [how Rails renders your view files and controller actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490508/what-ruby-technique-does-rails-use-to-make-my-controller-methods-render-views).