# Is it possible to stop Rails from rendering views for actions not defined in controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionview, actioncontroller

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599404/rails-doesnt-need-index-method-in-controller-defined), I'd like to know if there is a way to override that new rails behaviour. I run into a security issue with a forgotten view, that was suddenly exposed although the action was not defined in my Controller. I think it'd be better to stop Rails from rendering those not-defined actions and after that cleaning my unused views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your routes for that controller to not route to those actions.

```
resources :users, :except => [:index, :destroy]
resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
```

Those routes will become non-routable even if the views exists, you can then deal with the views as needed.

Comment: Thanks ! that's really a workaround, but it would imply checking all the routes in a big project can be a decent ammount of work. I was wondering if this behaviour could be switch of with configuration...

Comment: @dgilperez, Fair enough. Unfortunately I don't have the answer to that one up my sleeve. Good luck with it.

Comment: just checking old questions, I ended up thinking this was the way to go. Marking as answered, better late than never :)